# What is the difference between "depend" and "depends"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, verb-agreement

Could someone explain the difference between *depend* and *depends*?

When do I need to add the "s" at the end?

Comment: Search "Subject verb agreement"  online and look for singular and plural conjugations.

Answer (score 4):

To put it simply, subject-verb agreement.
What it means is that if the subject is singular, the verb shall be plural and vice-versa.

- > He depends on his father for money.

  (Here, the subject is singular, hence the verb is plural)
- > They depend on their father for money.

Comment: I believe this question is more about the usage of "depend on", "depends on", and "depending on", not simply the subject-verb agreement. Someone who can put up a question with such perfect grammar, would already know about that basic rule.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, firstly we need to know about person and number. In the English language, person is classified into 3 types and number is classified into 2 types.

1. First Person:
   Singular number: I, me, mine
   Plural number: we, us, our etc.
2. Second Person: you, your etc.
3. Third Person:
   Singular number: he, she, It, Nazmul(Name).
   Plural number: They, their etc.

When the sentence is present tense and the subject is **Third Person singular number**, then the verb would be in plural form(depends).

For example,

- > Jake depends on green plants to live.
- > Jake's pets depend on green plants to live.

Answer (score 0):

for the subject "he", "she", or "it", we use verb+s/es 
if *plural* and "you", we use verb (no adding s/es)